# iOS [[MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery] collections] returns "Playback History" at the first run

Tags: ios, collections, mpmediaquery

I called [[MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery] collections] and the results contains "Playback History" only at first run after user allows access to media library. If I restart the app and do the same query, the "Playback History" entry is gone. How can I remove it at first run?

Answer (score 0):

So far there is no known way to remove it, however a UserDefaults property like "firstLoad" can be used to retry the query if it's the first time to remove those extra playlists.